# Realm Migration Error

Tags: realm, realm-migration

I have a migration file which is as follows:-

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
        if(oldVersion == 1){

            RealmObjectSchema replyDBschema = schema.create("ReplyDB");
            replyDBschema.addField("date",String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY);
            replyDBschema.addField("id",int.class);
            replyDBschema.addField("conversationId",String.class);
            replyDBschema.addField("replyFrom",String.class);
            replyDBschema.addField("reply",String.class);

            RealmObjectSchema conversationDBschema = schema.create("ConversationDB");
            conversationDBschema.addField("conversationId",String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY);
            conversationDBschema.addField("id",String.class);
            conversationDBschema.addField("parentId",int.class);
            conversationDBschema.addField("topic",String.class);
            conversationDBschema.addField("date",String.class);
            conversationDBschema.addField("typeOfConversation",String.class);
            conversationDBschema.addField("studentId",int.class);
            conversationDBschema.addRealmListField("replyDBList", schema.get("ReplyDB"));

            if (!schema.get("ActivityDB").hasField("conversationDB")) {
                schema.get("ActivityDB").addRealmObjectField("conversationDB", conversationDBschema);
            }
            //schema.get("ActivityDB").addRealmObjectField("conversationDB",schema.get("ConversationDB"));

            oldVersion++;
        }
    }
}
```

Its because I have added two new Database file namely ReplyDB.class and ConversationDB.class.
Also I have edited ActivityDB to have ConversationDB object inside it.
And for all these I created the above migration file.

I am calling the migration file from the following Realm file

```
public class RealmApplication extends CalligraphyApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);

        final RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("parents.realm").schemaVersion(2).migration(new Migration()).build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);
        Realm.getInstance(configuration);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().close();
        super.onTerminate();
    }
}
```

Also I have tested by using the debugger the realm migration is getting called.

However the application is crashing throwing the following error:-

```
Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Missing field 'conversationDB' in existing Realm file. Either remove field or migrate using io.realm.internal.Table.addColumn().
                                                                      at io.realm.ActivityDBRealmProxy.validateTable(ActivityDBRealmProxy.java:814)
                                                                      at io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator.validateTable(DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java:85)
                                                                      at io.realm.Realm.initializeRealm(Realm.java:480)
                                                                      at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidateFromCache(Realm.java:423)
                                                                      at io.realm.Realm.createInstance(Realm.java:387)
                                                                      at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:346)
                                                                      at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:284)
                                                                      at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:301)
                                                                      at ai.edbox.parents.utils.RealmApplication.onCreate(RealmApplication.java:18)
                                                                      at ai.edbox.parents.utils.FabricApplication.onCreate(FabricApplication.java:14)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5403)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Please help me to resolve this error. Thank you.

Comment: The default version of a Realm is 0 if it was previously unversioned, so maybe `oldVersion == 0`?

Comment: No, I have set the schema version version to 1. And now I am setting it to 2.

Comment: The code looks correct, so not sure what is happening there. Best guess would be to debug step through the migration code and verify that all the assumptions holds true.